# php drop-down menu from MYSQL, how to return other column value?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm having a input form that asks for a location. The locations are stored in a mysql db and have an id (colomn: id and column: location).

I have a drop down menu that is generated from those records in the db:

```
    <select name="location">

    <?php                         
            $query="SELECT location FROM locations";
                $result=mysql_query($query) or die;

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $location=$row['location'];

            echo "<option>$location</option>";
    ?>

    </select>
```

This all works. When the form is sumbitted, I obviously get a POST[location] for example "Belgium".

Let's say Belgium is the location in my db and has id 5, how can I return the ID as the POST variable from the dropdown box, instead of the location. Ofcourse I want the dropdown to show the locations, and not the ID's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the value attribute as below (2nd answer) with the ID and will be returned instead of it's content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each option can take a value and show another string so use `value="my_value"` for each option inside the select tag

```
<select name="location">
    <?php                         
        $query="SELECT id, location FROM locations";
        $result=mysql_query($query);

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['location'] . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

now your `POST['location']` will contain the db id for selected location

Comment: Frate, echo is a language construct. Accepts comma separate arguments. Why concatenate when you are just outputting stuff? `echo '1', '2', '3'; // works without concatenation`

Answer (score 1):

if you change the SQl query to include the ID of the location, 
you can assign that value to the dropdown selected value.

```
<select name="location">
<?php   
$query="SELECT id, location FROM locations";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $location=$row['location'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$location."</option>";
?>
</select>
```

Comment: And only one escapes HTML and does not concatenate on echo... which is kind of sad :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from locations;

$ID=$row['ID'];
```

Replace ID by the ID-name of your column ofcourse.

If you say select * from locations you can do something like this:

```
$row['anyCOLUMNNAME']
```

You can choose any column you like and use that information from that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="location">
<?php                         
// select columns you need, separate by , (comma)
$query = "SELECT `column1`, `column2` FROM `locations`;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // selected columns become accessible in $row array
    // value attribute needs to be escaped here
    echo '<option value="', htmlentities($row['column1']),'">',
        htmlentities($row['column2']), '</option>'; // escape label too
    // <option> does not accept HTML in label so it should be escaped
} // done!
?>
</select>
```

^ **this** *(read comments for explanations)*